# Laravel Sail - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I followed the tutorial of [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail) and  it is working fine, but if I clone the repo (*docker-compose up*), in another machine, I get the following error when trying to run migrations inside the container:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: create table
> `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
> `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default
> character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Already tried some solutions but nothing worked.

My **database.php** file:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

My **.env** file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=code_challenge
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Have you checked that your `mysql` container is running?

Comment: Yep, it is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to connect to DB container via socket from different container.

There are two separate containers - Laravel and MySQL. Thinks of it like two separate servers.

When you have both **unix_socket** and **db_host** in env, you are telling laravel to connect to db at specified host via unix_socket. That is why  it didn't work.

When you update the **unix_socket** env, laravel try to connect to DB via TCP and it work.

*P.S: I know this issue is already resolved for you. But in case someone else stumble upon this question, they should have some explanation on why it work and how to fix it in the future.*

Answer (score 4):

Inside .env file you need to change this:
`DB_HOST=mysql`

Answer (score 2):

So, on database.php I removed the socket value:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '')
```

And in .env I maintained the previous values.

Not sure what caused the problem, but it's working now.

Comment: Also ran composer update inside the container

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but the output seems a little bit different here. In case anyone look for an answer here like me, I'll just write down my solution.

If I set `DB_HOST=localhost`, I get this error in my app

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

If I set `DB_HOST=mysql`, which should be the right one as this is the container's name, it works fine in my app, but error in the `php artisan migrate`

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: No such host is known.
```

It seems like my terminal and my app doesn't recognize the same name.
My solution is to change the `DB_HOST` as below and it works:

```
DB_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

Comment: Fixed the issue for me (also commented the unix socket line in database.php btw, but that didn't fix the issue by itself and I had to do what this answer says as well).

Answer (score 0):

One of the important point is you should notice that, if you have **multi localhost defined** in your system like (127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, ...) you should define the **DB_HOST value with 127.0.0.1**
I had the same issue and it solved by set DB_HOST value with 127.0.0.1